# The order of operations in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators

I'm trying to understand the order of operators in Python. I tried the following:

```
var1 = None
var2 = 0
print( (var1 is None) != var2 )
print( (var1 is None) != var2 is True )     ###
print( ((var1 is None) != var2) is True )
print( (var1 is None) != (var2 is True) )
print( True is True )
```

I expected all to be True. However the result is:

```
True
False
True
True
True
```

How could the second print() gives me a False result?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to [comparison chaining](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons), so this (perhaps surprisingly) simplifies to

```py
>>> None == 0 is True
<stdin>:1: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
False
>>> None == 0 and 0 is True
<stdin>:1: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
False
```

Some other examples

```py
>>> 1 is 1 is 1
<stdin>:1: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
True
>>> 1 < 2 < 3 < 4 < 5
True
>>> 4 < 2 < 3
False
>>> multiplayer_sandwich_order = "€35"
>>> 10 < int(multiplayer_sandwich_order[1:]) < 40
True
>>> 10 < int(multiplayer_sandwich_order[1:]) < 30
False
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ti7. It is chained together with ```and```. So the second is True and False, which is False in the end.

Comment: @lay anytime! if this answers your Question, please mark it as the Answer with the check to its left to gain reputation and help the community!