# How is `a == b is not None` interpreted?

Tags: python

during a personal project I needed to evaluate if two variables were equal, but not None.
So the condition should be `True` if they are both equal (a=5, b=5), but not in other cases, or when they are both None (a=None, b=None), it should be `False`

So I typed in my interpreter `a == b is not None` and had the behavior I wanted.

```
Python 3.9.9 (tags/v3.9.9:ccb0e6a, Nov 15 2021, 18:08:50) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = None
>>> b = None
>>> a == b is not None
False
>>> a = 5
>>> a == b is not None
False
>>> b = 5
>>> a == b is not None
True
>>>
```

But I wanted to double check if this was the intended behavior, as in a special case in the evaluation of condition (like the phrase `x is not None` which means `not x is None`) ? Or maybe it is just the normal way Python would evaluate it ?

Because if we evaluate it normally, we would first check if `a == b`, and then compare that with `is not None` which would always result in `True`, but in reality when we test it, the behavior is  different. Also I have **never** in 5 years of Python programming seen this condition, so I find it pretty rare, therefore I am not sure if it was already documented

Comment: I recently Answered another similar question which may have some further surprising/helpful examples! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689599/the-order-of-operations-in-python

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are [chained comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons).  It's *exactly* equivalent to

```py
a == b and b is not None
```

in each of the cases.

Little more gentle introduction available [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/chaining-comparison-operators-python/):

This is most commonly used (in my experience) with `<` or `>`, e.g.

```py
# reads like a normal math expression
if 0 < x < 10:
    print('valid range')  # or whatever.
```